# Control-break logic reading a text file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to read a file; and when a value changes, grab that line.

```
$log = Import-Csv .\logfile.txt -Header Date, OS
```

Here's a sample of data from a text file:

```
11/19/2019,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1809
11/19/2019,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1809
11/19/2019,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1809
11/19/2019,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1903
11/19/2019,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1903
5/5/2020,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1909
5/6/2020,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1909
5/6/2020,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1909
```

When the OS changes to a new version, grab that line to show the date and the OS when the OS changed.  I'm hoping the output would look something like this:

```
11/19/2019,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1809
11/19/2019,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1903
5/5/2020,Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1909
```

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the previous value with a variable in a loop:

```
$lastOS = ''
Import-Csv .\logfile.txt -Header Date, OS |ForEach-Object {
  if($lastOS -ne $_.OS){
    # new OS, output current record 
    $_

    # and update our tracking variable
    $lastOS = $_.OS
  }
}
```

Which, with the sample data provided, gives us:

```
Date       OS
----       --
11/19/2019 Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1809
11/19/2019 Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1903
5/5/2020   Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1909
```